# Выбрать элементы, сумма которых наиболее близка к заданной (сверху)

Tags: алгоритм, математика, комбинаторика

Прошу помощи в вопросе:

Есть элементы: 30, 70, 90, 100.

Есть сумма, которую вводит пользователь.

Если пользователь введет `60`, то эта сумма не меняется

Если пользователь введет `45`-> сумма `60`

`155->160(30+70+30+30)`

`150->150(90+30+30)`

и т. д.

Элементы внутри суммы можно использовать сколько угодно раз.

Подскажите быстрый алгоритм, позволяющий сделать это.

Comment: Лично я не понял, попробуйте описать подробнее. Что такое кратности? Сумма чего?

Comment: есть поле инпут, в которой стоит наименьшая кратность 30( если пользователь нажмет вверх, то сумма  становится 60)
Если пользователь введет некую сумму в инпут, например 155, то должно в инпут поставляться 160 (см пример выше)

Comment: А почему именно 160, а не 150 (30+30+30+30+30)? Опишите алгоритм подробнее

Comment: Кажется, я понял, что нужно. [Это](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-length-subarray-sum-greater-given-value/)?

Comment: А зачем даны 90 и 100, может их сократить сразу, потому как 90 это 30*3, а 100 это 70+30. т.е. те же итоговые пороги округления можно набрать из первых двух чисел.

Comment: @АндрейNOP Не 150, потому что в задаче сказано "_Найти быстрый алгоритм, позволяющий округлять в большую сторону._". В меньшую округлять не надо

Comment: А каких порядков могут быть числа на входе?

Comment: @Rabin, посмотрите вопрос, ничего ли я не исказил своей правкой

Comment: @АндрейNOP,  все верно, спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Это задача - один из подвидов `subset sum` или `coin change` - о том, как расплатиться монетами из заданного набора с возможным избытком.

Решается динамическим программированием - например, можно создать массив длиной `sum + наименьшая монета`, заполнить его возможными раскладами и посмотреть, какая первая ячейка заполнена, начиная с ячейки `sum`.

Answer (score 1):

Не самый быстрый, но довольно простой рекурсивный алгоритм (код на C#). Вам ведь с чего-то надо начать?

```
static int GetSum(int value, int[] nominals)
{
    if (value <= 0) return 0;
    int res = nominals[0] + GetSum(value - nominals[0], nominals);
    for (int i = 1; i < nominals.Length; ++i)
    {
        int candidat = nominals[i] + GetSum(value - nominals[i], nominals);
        if (res > candidat) res = candidat;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Тест:

```
int[] nominals = { 30, 70, 90, 100 };
Console.WriteLine(GetSum(45, nominals));  // 60
Console.WriteLine(GetSum(60, nominals));  // 60
Console.WriteLine(GetSum(155, nominals)); // 160
Console.WriteLine(GetSum(150, nominals)); // 150
```

Если добавить мемоизацию:

```
static Dictionary<int, int> mem = new Dictionary<int, int>();
static int GetSum(int value, int[] nominals)
{
    if (value <= 0) return 0;
    if (mem.TryGetValue(value, out var res)) return res;
    res = nominals[0] + GetSum(value - nominals[0], nominals);
    for (int i = 1; i < nominals.Length; ++i)
    {
        int candidat = nominals[i] + GetSum(value - nominals[i], nominals);
        if (res > candidat) res = candidat;
    }
    return mem[value] = res;
}
```

то достаточно быстро берет на входе и такие числа:

```
Console.WriteLine(GetSum(54321, nominals)); // 54330
```